# Passar variável PHP para "arquivo" javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Eu consigo passar uma variável *PHP* para *javascript* se estiver na mesma página, mas o problema é que se eu jogar esse código para um arquivo *JS* ele não funciona.

Comment: o q a variavel pagina traz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim tem como fazer desde que o javascript não seja proveniente de uma fonte externa.

**Pagina PHP**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">var param = "<?= $pagina ?>";</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paginacao.js"></script>
```

**paginacao.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var pagina = param;
    jQuery('#btnpaginas').click(function(){
        pagina++;
        var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "paginacao.php?pagina="+pagina,
            data: dados,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $(".paginacao").html(data);

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não exista uma forma de passar variáveis do *PHP* para um arquivo `.js` externo e estático, já que o processamento é feito no próprio arquivo `.php` que está sendo executado.

Comment: Pode crer. Acho que não tem problema nenhum você deixar o seu código dentro da `<script>` mesmo. Se olhar o código-fonte de sites como Google, Facebook, etc, sempre vai ter algum *script* assim. :)